# Long Query: "gradethis" package in R-cloud

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

Here is one of the dataset I have been practicing on R-cloud and this the approach:

```
data_long %>%
  filter(Indicator == "Emissions")



glimpse(data_long)

## This is suppose to return 2 columns Year & Emissions, it ends up aggregating values:
## Emissions
## 1417688795

data_long %>%
  filter(Indicator == "Emissions") %>%
  group_by(Year) %>%
  summarize(Emissions = sum(Value))
 
## Another -- Error in `check_aesthetics()`:
## ! Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1): x  

data_long %>%
  filter(Indicator == "Emissions") %>%
  group_by(Year) %>%
  summarize(Emissions = sum(Value)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = Emissions)) +
  geom_line(size = 1.5)
```

I am assuming there is a issue with one of the packages (gradethis) or (learnr) as I am using R-cloud, are there any working limitations with it? any suggestions?

Thanks,
Vikram

Comment: Welcome to SO! Do you mind sharing a sample dput(head(df))?

Comment: data_long <- CO2_emissions %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(-Country, -Year, -Label),
               names_to = "Indicator",
               values_to = "Value")

Comment: What is CO2_emisions ?

Comment: Contact me on Telegram `julauto`